# How to from Old Query PHP to Query with Prepared Statements with PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, prepared-statement

Iam bringing my old code (vunerable in so many ways) to new standards with PDO.
The problem is, i'm getting no return, no error message, no nothing.
What my code do is the following: Makes a query to the DB and if there is any result ($resultado) it creates an order of the data in arrays.
Can please someone give me a help?
I tried the Array approach and the Object approach, no donuts :/

Old Code:

```
$sql_code =
   "SELECT news_id, news_title, news_date, news_resume
   FROM news
   WHERE news_show = 'S'
   ORDER BY news_date DESC
   ";

   $result = mysql_query($sql_code);

   if ($result) {
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      for ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
      $aID[]     = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_id");
      $aTitle[]  = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_title");
      $aDate[]   = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_date");
      $aResume[] = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_resume");
      }
   }
?>
```

New Code that doesnt work:

```
try
      {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT   news_id, news_title, news_date, news_resume
                                   FROM     news
                                   WHERE    news_show = :newsS
                                   ORDER BY news_date DESC");

            $stmt->execute(array('newsS' => 'S'));

            while ($sql_code = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $result = mysql_query($sql_code);
            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error:". $e->getMessage();
        }

   $result = mysql_query($sql_code);

   if ($result)
   {
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      for ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
      {
      $aID[]     = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_id");
      $aTitle[]  = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_title");
      $aDate[]   = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_date");
      $aResume[] = mysql_result($result, $i, "news_resume");
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: simple: you're mixing MySQL APIs. which you can't do. Use the same one from connection to query. No gray areas. You can have a rum & coke though.

Comment: i am upvoting just for the title / desire

Comment: plus `fetchall` that should have a capital A. Now who's got the balls to submit an answer? Edit: *how about you Sam?* - @JayBlanchard - grin

Comment: A little error checking would go a long, long way on this code.

Comment: *It sure does Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *I am almost with @DrewPierce on this Ralph.* +1 for the desire to get it right. -1 for failure to use error checking.

Comment: *I'm walking away from this one Sam* - @JayBlanchard - See you on the wild side 'o town ;-)

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns an array containing all the results. Why are you passing that to `mysql_query()`? Even if you could mix APIs, the argument to `mysql_query()` is the SQL string, not the results of a previous query.

Comment: You also don't need to call `fetchAll()` in a `while` loop -- you do that when you're just getting one row at a time with `fetch()`.

Comment: Hint `$result = mysql_query($sql_code);` is still deprecated code (not the only place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PDO, you don't call any `mysql_XXX` functions, you have to use PDO methods for everything.

`$stmt->fetchAll()` returns all the rows of the results. To process it, just use a `foreach` loop.

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT   news_id, news_title, news_date, news_resume
                           FROM     news
                           WHERE    news_show = :newsS
                           ORDER BY news_date DESC");

    $stmt->execute(array('newsS' => 'S'));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $aId[] = $row['news_id'];
        $aTitle[] = $row['news_title'];
        $aDate[] = $row['news_date'];
        $aResume[] = $row['news_resume'];
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error:". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly that! I'm not a lazy person as the funny comments suggested i was, i'm just trying to learn! Community need more people like you! You was right!